# Parse SIP packet in C

Tags: c, parsing, sip

I am trying to parse a SIP packet and get some information out of it. To be more specific, the packet looks like this

```
REGISTER sip:open-ims.test SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.64:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK1489975971
From: <sip:alice@open-ims.test>;tag=1627897650
To: <sip:alice@open-ims.test>
Call-ID: 1097412971
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:alice@192.168.1.64:5060;line=5fc3b39f127158d>;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:46f525fe-3f60-11e0-bec1-d965d1488cfa>"
Authorization: Digest username="alice@open-ims.test", realm="open-ims.test", nonce=" ", uri="sip:open-ims.test", response=" "
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: UCT IMS Client
Expires: 600000
Supported: path
Supported: gruu
Content-Length: 0
```

Now, from that packet I need to extract the following :

- The value after "From: " ( in this case `<sip:alice@open-ims.test>` )
- The value after "Contact: " ( in this case `<sip:alice@192.168.1.64` )
- The value after "username" ( in this case `alice@open-ims.test` )

My code so far is this

```
char * tch;
      char * saved;                    
      tch = strtok (payload,"<>;");
      while (tch != NULL)
      { 
        int savenext = 0;              
        if (!strcmp(tch, "From: "))     
        {                              
          savenext = 1;                
        }                              

        tch = strtok (NULL, "<>;");
        if (savenext == 1)             
        {                              
          saved = tch;                 
        }                              
      }
      printf ("### SIP Contact: %s ###\n", saved);  
        }
    }
```

Where payload contains the packet as described above.

However, when I run my program, it will result in a segmentation fault. The weird thing is that if I use in strtok the characters "<>;: " and in strcmp the value "sip" the message will parse successfully and it will keep the saved value. But I need to parse all three of the upper values.

Would a sip library help me more with my problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general when you need to parse or construct structured text like this it's a good idea to use a library because there are always corner cases in the encoding that you'd need to handle - and someone else has done that work for you. Assuming, that is, you can find something simple and lightweight enough to link in to what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this could work

```
char * tch;
        char * saved;                    
        tch = strtok (payload,"<>;\n\"");
        while (tch != NULL)
        { 
            int savenext = 0;              
            if (strncmp(tch, "From",4)==0)   
            {                                 
            tch = strtok (NULL, "<>;\n\"");
            saved = tch;                 
            printf ("   SIP From: %s \n", saved); 
            }   
            else if (strncmp(tch, "Contact",7)==0) 
            {                                 
            tch = strtok (NULL, "<>;\n\"");
            saved = tch;                 
            printf ("   SIP Cont: %s \n", saved); 
            } 
            if (strncmp(tch, "Authorization",13)==0)  
            {                                     
            tch = strtok (NULL, "<>;\n\"");
            saved = tch;                 
            printf ("   SIP User: %s \n", saved);
```

Answer (score 3):

Echoing the comment provided by [*Rup*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup), I too would recommend using a library as all the heavy lifting has been done for you and you can spend more time focusing on what you are attempting to accomplish with the parsed information.

The [***GNU oSIP library***](http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/) may be a good place to start.

From the [online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/doc/html/):

> ```
>    SIP parser:
>    ==========
> ```
>
> The initial feature implemented in
>   osip is a SIP parser. There is not
>   much to say about it: it is capable of
>   parsing and reformating SIP requests
>   and answers.
>
> The details of the parsing tools
>   available are listed below:
>
> 1  SIP request/answer
>    2  SIP uri
>    3  specific headers
>    4  Via
>    5  CSeq
>    6  Call-ID
>    7  To, From, Route, Record-Route...
>    8  Authentication related headers
>    9  Content related headers
>    10 Accept related headers
>    11 ...
>    12 Generic header
>    13 Attachement parser (should support mime)
>    14 SDP parser

Answer (score 2):

Use a parser if you possibly can. SIP syntax has a grammar so complex that many ABNF parsers can't handle the RFC 3261 ABNF. If you're still thinking writing it yourself is a good idea, you should get familiar with RFC 4475, the SIP torture tests because you should use them if this is going to interact with other systems, and because it will show you why it's so hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Read each line and search for each of your substrings ('From:', 'Contact:', 'username') using `strstr()`.

When you encounter a line that contains one of your keywords, split it with `strtok()` and extract the piece you need accordingly.

I don't know if you need a full-blown SIP lib for extracting these three things, but if you might need to parse more of the packet in the future, it might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @wtfm8. But the thing is I can't read each line since it's all a big string. I agree that adding a sip lib wouldn't be the best for such a light task.

Answer (score 0):

For strtok use with "<>;",  I'd expect your packet to be split into something like the following (newlines removed)

```
REGISTER sip:open-ims.test SIP/2.0Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.64:5060

rport

branch=z9hG4bK1489975971From:

sip:alice@open-ims.test
```

None of these will match

```
 if (!strcmp(tch, "From: "))
```

You'd either need to modify your parser or search through the string returned by strtok for "From: ".

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` doesn't have to use the same set of delimiters every time.  You can use a colon when you are expecting a field label and leave it off when you are expecting the right hand side.